# PHP undefined offset (not an error) try catch

Tags: php

I would like to list (upto) six of the remaining assignments due for the acedemic year onto a webpage.
The data for the remaining assignments comes from a mysql db.
When there are six or more assignments left, the webpage displays the info correctly.
If there are less than six left, then i get a undefined offset error (and i understand why).
Basically, i am trying to programmatically ignore the offset error.

I've tried looking and the following:
try/catches in the

php.
tried using (in the foreach loop)
    if($row['name'] == null){$row['name'] = "";}
etc.

index.php

include('getdata.php');

```
$nextAssArray0 = getNextAssessments($courseInfoArray[0], 0);
$nextAssArray1 = getNextAssessments($courseInfoArray[0], 1);
$nextAssArray2 = getNextAssessments($courseInfoArray[0], 2);
$nextAssArray3 = getNextAssessments($courseInfoArray[0], 3);
$nextAssArray4 = getNextAssessments($courseInfoArray[0], 4);
$nextAssArray5 = getNextAssessments($courseInfoArray[0], 5);

<div class="col-sm-4">
<h3>You have <?php echo '' ?> assignments left</h3>
 <p>Assignment: <?php echo $nextAssArray0[0]; ?> is due on <?php echo $nextAssArray0[1]; ?></p>
 <p>Assignment: <?php echo $nextAssArray1[0]; ?> is due on <?php echo $nextAssArray1[1]; ?></p>
 <p>Assignment: <?php echo $nextAssArray2[0]; ?> is due on <?php echo $nextAssArray2[1]; ?></p>
 <p>Assignment: <?php echo $nextAssArray3[0]; ?> is due on <?php echo $nextAssArray3[1]; ?></p>
 <p>Assignment: <?php echo $nextAssArray4[0]; ?> is due on <?php echo $nextAssArray4[1]; ?></p>
 <p>Assignment: <?php echo $nextAssArray5[0]; ?> is due on <?php echo $nextAssArray5[1]; ?>
 </p>
</div>
```

getdata.php

```
function getNextAssessments($courseID, $offset)
{
try
{
    include('dbconn.php');
    $array = array();
    $stm = $conn->prepare("CALL getUpcomingAssignments(:courseID, :offset)");
    $stm->bindParam(':courseID', $courseID);
    $stm->bindParam(':offset', $offset);
    $stm->execute();
    foreach ($stm->fetchALL() as $row)
    {
        array_push($array, $row['name']);
        array_push($array, $row['due_date']);
        array_push($array, $row['tem']);
    }
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    $array = array('','','');
}

return $array;
```

}

I am after the following functionality:
1) if there is only three assignments left - then only three

display.
2) if there is ten assignments left - then only six are displayed.
3) if there are no assignments left - then nothing is displayed in those

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is not a good idea to make SQL query for every database record.  Remove limit from query, and put all your assesments in array. Then do something like this:

```
<h3>You have <?php echo count($assesments) ?> assignments left</h3>
<?php
foreach($assesments as $assesment){
 echo "<p>Assignment: {$assesment[0]} is due on {$assesment[1]} ?></p>"
}
?>
```

Also I would recommend changing your code so you have array like `$assesment['dueDate']` instead of `$assesment[1]`.

Comment: Thank you Patryk. I have changed my sql query. I have added the code you have suggested. If I comment out everything from "<?php" to "?>" my page displays the correct number of assignments to go. If I uncomment that code a recieve the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp64\www\index.php on line 122. Is there something I am not doing correctly?

Comment: Sorry, that should read ... my page displays an incorrect number of assignments to go...

Comment: Yes, thats my fault. Missing semicolon after `echo` in `foreach`. Please upvote if answer was helpful :)

Comment: Thanks again Patryk. You really helped me solve this. I changed a bit of code to get it to work. The sql query returns 2 columns per row. `code`<h3>You have <?php echo (sizeof($assesments)/2) ?> assignments left</h3> <?php
    for ($x = 0; $x < sizeof($assesments); $x = $x + 2)
    {
        echo "<p>Assignment: {$assesments[$x]} is due on {$assesments[$x+1]} </p>";
    }

?> it does exactly what I want now. I dont not have enough rep to vote atm.

Comment: So you can accept the answer if your problem was solved :) Glad I could help.